# I can't resolve an error with Duplicity on Ubuntu

Tags: duplicity

```
env PASSPHRASE='passphrase here' duplicity --encrypt-key=XXXXXXXX \
        --sign-key=XXXXXXXX --include /home/USER/Documents \
        webdavs://user:password@192.168.0.3:5005
Command line error: Expected 2 args, got 1
```

I've checked for typographic errors. I've checked with duplicity's documentation and third-party duplicity documentation and nothing seems to address it. Any ideas? I'm guessing it's something easy that I'm missing, but it's been days and I just can't find what's causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

You've omitted the source directory.  See the manual, and look carefully at the examples, e.g.

> Finally, duplicity recognizes several include/exclude options.  For instance, the following will backup
> the root directory, but exclude /mnt, /tmp, and /proc:

```
          duplicity --exclude /mnt --exclude /tmp --exclude /proc / file:///usr/local/backup
```

If you want to backup only /home/[USER]/Documents, just say

```
  duplicity --encrypt-key=XXXXXXXX \
    --sign-key=XXXXXXXX /home/USER/Documents \
    webdavs://user:password@192.168.0.3:5005
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Duplicity, because I thrive just by using Rsync, and content hashing, and a few external drives, and an off shore location, and all of this is for miscellaneous reasons easier for me; but I've used Duplicity in the past, so I'm going to try to add a couple cents:

If you look carefully, your command line seems to show:

- The (wrongly performed?) setting of an environment variable. Anyway, not the question here.
- The command (`duplicity`).
- An *option* argument: `--encrypt-key=XXXXXXXX`.
- Another one: `--sign-key=XXXXXXXX`.
- And yet another one: `--include /home/USER/Documents`.
- No "source" argument?
- One argument (destination?): `webdavs://user:password@192.168.0.3:5005`.

So if it says:

> Command line error: Expected 2 args, got 1

I guess that's right?

Doesn't it intuitively feel like you are missing one of both "source + destination" arguments?

In a similar way, Rsync can often be used passing many option arguments and then two arguments for source and destination.

Cheers,